# Dynamic update of Highstock multiple series with use of Rest api data( Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, highcharts

With laravel i  created Highcharts from consumed Rest API Link(Spring app) (http://85614a50.ngrok.io/api/devices) with 2 series(axes)

First series do a visualization of Memory in time so object contains(Memory usage, timestamp)

Second series do a visualization of CPU in time and object contains(CPU Usage,timestamp)

[image]

This all results are shown statically, now i want to visualise dynamically on charts.

I created a function which do a call of rest api within every 5 second, and event function inside Chart refreshing every 5 second.

It work but axes does not shows me a data from Series(it shows some random numbers because x and y variables are declare as current time and random numbers).

So i know that i must call a Series inside x,y variables.But didn't figure how. Did someone maybe know how to solve this problem ?

P.S.

In case you declare variables and chart(data) is not updated probably it will happen because i didn't turn on java client application so it showing just same data.I not able to keep application truned on because lack of memory on my harddisk. Only monitoring app is truned on so link is working!

My code Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLERGG   (If you open this link it takes 5 seconds for charts to appear)

***Home..blade.php***

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <style type="text/css">
#container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-lg-4 {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    min-width: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    height: 400px;

}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 10%; /* Location of the box */
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}  
#container.modal{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;


}




        </style>

<h2 class="text-center" >{{$user->first_name}} Charts </h2>


<div id="container">
    <div class="row">

   </div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    setInterval(getHighChart, 10000); //30 seconds onload="getHighChart()" 
});

function getHighChart() {

$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8000/api/devices", function( data ) {


console.log(data);

var mappedClientsAllias = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, "clientName"), "clientName");
var mappedClients = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, "Id_client"), "Id_client");

var clients = [];

_.forEach(mappedClients, function(Id_client, clientName) {
  var tempClient = {
    Allias: mappedClientsAllias[clientName],
    name: Id_client,
    data: [],
    memory:[]
  };
  tempClient2=tempClient;
  _.forEach(data, function(tempData) {
    if (Id_client=== tempData.Id_client**strong text**) {
      _.forEach(tempData.clientData, function(clientData) {
        tempClient.data.push([
          clientData.timestamp,
          clientData.cpuUsage,
        ]);
         tempClient.memory.push([
          clientData.timestamp,
          clientData.memoryUsage,
        ]);


      });
    }
  });


  clients.push(tempClient);
});




console.log("clients", clients);
var chart = _.forEach(clients, function(client) {

  $('<div class="col-lg-4">')
    .css("position", "relative")
    .appendTo("#container")
    .highcharts("StockChart", {
      marker: {
        states: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      time: {
        timezoneOffset: -2 * 60
      },
    exporting: {
                buttons: {

                      customButton3: {
                        text: 'Zooming',
                        //make fullscreen of chart with size change
                        onclick: function(e) {
                           var w = $(window).width();
                           var h = $(window).height();
                        $(e.target).closest('#container').toggleClass('modal');
  if($(e.target).closest('#container').hasClass('modal')) {
    $('.col-lg-4').hide();
    $(e.target).closest('.col-lg-4').show();
      $('.col-lg-4').css({
                  'width': w * .9,
                'height': h * .9
            });  

  } else {
    $('.col-lg-4').show();
     $('.col-lg-4').css({
                 'width': '',
                'height': ''

            });

  }
$(e.target).closest('.col-lg-4').highcharts().reflow();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
      rangeSelector: {
        y: 15,
        buttons: [
          {
            count: 1,
            type: "minute",
            text: "Sec"
          },
          {
            count: 1,
            type: "hour",
            text: "Min"
          },
          {
            count: 1,
            type: "day",
            text: "Hours"
          },

          {
            type: "all",
            text: "All"
          }
        ],
        title: "hours",
        inputEnabled: true,
        _selected: 1
      },

      title: {
        text: client.Allias
      },
      yAxis: [{

                labels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'CPU'
                },
                height: '50%',
                lineWidth: 2,
                   color: 'red'
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Memory'
                },
                top: '70%',
                height: '50%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2,

            }],
      xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: "Client usage"
        },
         top: '20%',
        type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          second: "%H:%M:%S",
          minute: "%H:%M",
          hour: "%H:%M",
          day: "%e. %b",
          week: "%e. %b",
          day: "%Y<br/>%b-%d"
        }
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false,
          }
        }
      },

       series: [{
        name: "Memory USAGE",
        data: client.memory.sort()
    },  // Add a new series
    {
        name: "Cpu USAGE",
         yAxis: 1,
          color: 'red',
        data: client.data.sort()

    }],

      chart: {
        renderTo: "container",
        height:400,
     events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
      },

    });



});

  });

}




</script>




 @endsection
```

***Layouts.app***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Master thesis application</title>

   <!-- Jquery --> 


  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Import css file-->
<link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
  <body>
     @include('doc.header')

   @include('doc.nav')
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
    <div class="container">
     @include('doc.ifno')


    @yield('main')
    </div> <!-- /container -->

 @include('doc.Navfoot')


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thy you just won't prepare whole series object with new data and call `chart.update({series: newSeriesObject})`?

Comment: You mean to create new series and call it or ?

Comment: Create new series object with changed `data` param only, and pass it to `update()` function.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLERGG you mean something like this, i created new 2 series objects with empty `data:` parm ? But i don't know which param of data i need to put if i want to  do update of chart

Comment: Your server with JSON is not working again, but actually I prepared the simple and minimal example which shows how you should do that. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/rjme6daz/

Comment: Now json it working sorry again, thanks a lot for answer but still i have no idea 
 which new data  from json i need to bring(if i call data from same json resource to new series object it will give me same params as first series object) to update series.Could you now help me please.I spent 3 days in soliving this problem I was not able to solve it:/

Comment: I don't know how to explain it much easier ;) If you're getting your JSON file every 5 seconds, you need to parse it just like before init your chart, and update it as it is done in my example above.

Comment: You mean something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqZERG  ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJOKRL?editors=1010 with update function and hard-code data(json)

Comment: Like that: https://jsfiddle.net/zspjekut/ , but timestamps of your updated data has very small interval, that's why the xAxis ticks are not visible.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, probably that why my axes disappear when i want to update charts with rest api from my localhost